# How can I make a JavaScript 'if' statement that connects to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an HTML and a JavaScript code so that after the alert(); function, then the HTML code will run.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
alert("Website showing in 3, 2, 1");
```

And after the person clicks okay from the alert box, then my HTML code will run. How do I make the HTML code run after the JavaScript code?

Comment: HTML code cannot be executed, it is a markup language. What do you want to do? If you want to update a part of the page, then you would use the DOM API (or JQuery) to do that.

Comment: I am trying to get the HTML code to run after the person read the alert(); function.

Comment: @Alex Did you read OlivierLiechti's comment? HTML doesn't 'execute', it renders... you can't render it on demand, but you can update the DOM to trigger a rerender.

Comment: Again: you cannot "run" HTML code. You can execute Javascript, but not HTML.

Comment: HTML code can't be executed. You might be able to use CSS to hide the page, and then edit the CSS with javascript after the alert.

Comment: If the `alert()` is in a `<script>` element at the top of the `<body>` or in the `<head>` then the rest of the page will not be rendered until the `alert()` is closed.

Comment: I'm guessing based on the question that @Alex is relatively new to web programming. They're certainly new to Stack Overflow, especially given that they've only asked one question and just got the "Informed" and "Autobiographer" badges within the last hour.

I've been new enough to topics before to not even be able to understand why a question I was asking wasn't well-posed. I hope to be that new to topics in the future.

Comment: The relationship between HTML, JavaScript, and CSS can be confusing to beginners. Since Alex doesn't seem to have an understanding of that relationship, it would have been more productive to *explain* what that relationship is in greater detail rather than just tersely saying things that are technically correct but not necessarily helpful to someone who is so new that they don't even have a grasp of the fundamentals.

Comment: And the downvotes certainly aren't welcoming.

Comment: @Alex, when asking questions, it might be helpful to put together a fiddle that represents the question you are asking. https://jsfiddle.net/ is a site that lets you building basic web pages from HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for sharing and testing. When you put together a fiddle, only include the bare minimum needed to illustrate the problem or question. It can also be helpful to phrase your questions from your end-users' perspective rather than or in addition to from a programmer's perspective, even after you've got more experience with HTML, JavaScript, and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your html content inside a div with `class='mydiv' id='div1'`
2. Add some css to hide your div, e.g
   `.mydiv { display:none; }`
3. After `alert()`, remove `mydiv` class from your div:

   `document.getElementById('div1').classList.remove('mydiv');`

Comment: while this would probably work, it doesn't keep the HTML from being rendered, it just keeps it from being displayed.  anyone with knowledge of the browser console could still get the entire content.  It's not really clear if this is what the OP is looking to do or not, though, since they seem to be using terminology that doesn't make sense in this context.

Comment: @Alex, if this answer worked for you, you should accept the answer as correct.

Comment: @Claies I just think that it may help to clarify how html should be used as OP might not be so familiar with it.